# Java 8 Map KeySet Stream not working as desired for use in Collector

Tags: java, collections, set, java-8, java-stream

I have been trying to learn Java 8's new functional interface features, and I am having some difficulty refactoring code that I have previously written.

As part of a test case, I want to store a list of read names in a Map structure in order to check to see if those reads have been "fixed" in a subsequent section of code. I am converting from an existing Map> data structure. The reason why I am flattening this datastructure is because the outer "String" key of the original Map is not needed in the subsequent analysis (I used it to segregate data from different sources before merging them in the intermediate data). Here is my original program logic:

```
public class MyClass {
  private Map<String, Map<String, Short>> anchorLookup;
  ...
  public void CheckMissingAnchors(...){
    Map<String, Boolean> anchorfound = new HashMap<>();

    // My old logic used the foreach syntax to populate the "anchorfound" map
    for(String rg : anchorLookup.keySet()){
      for(String clone : anchorLookup.get(rg).keySet()){
        anchorfound.put(clone, false);
      }
    }
    ...
    // Does work to identify the read name in the file. If found, the boolean in the map
    // is set to "true." Afterwards, the program prints the "true" and "false" counts in 
    // the map
   }
}
```

I attempted to refactor the code to use functional interfaces; however, I getting errors from my IDE (Netbeans 8.0 Patch 2 running Java 1.8.0_05):

```
public class MyClass {
  private Map<String, Map<String, Short>> anchorLookup;
  ...
  public void CheckMissingAnchors(...){

    Map<String, Boolean> anchorfound = anchorLookup.keySet()
      .stream()
      .map((s) -> anchorlookup.get(s).keySet())  // at this point I am expecting a 
      // Stream<Set<String>> which I thought could be "streamed" for the collector method
      // ; however, my IDE does not allow me to select the "stream()" method
      .sequential() // this still gives me a Stream<Set<String>>
      .collect(Collectors.toMap((s) -> s, (s) -> false);
      // I receive an error for the preceding method call, as Stream<Set<String>> cannot be 
      // converted to type String
    ...
   }
}
```

Is there a better way to create the "anchorfound" map using the Collection methods or is the vanilla Java "foreach" structure the best way to generate this data structure?

I apologize for any obvious errors in my code. My formal training was not in computer science but I would like to learn more about Java's implementation of functional programming concepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you need is a flatMap.

This way you convert each key of the outer map to a stream of the keys of the corresponding inner map, and then flatten them to a single stream of String.

```
public class MyClass {
  private Map<String, Map<String, Short>> anchorLookup;
  ...
  public void CheckMissingAnchors(...){

    Map<String, Boolean> anchorfound = anchorLookup.keySet()
      .stream()
      .flatMap(s -> anchorlookup.get(s).keySet().stream())
      .collect(Collectors.toMap((s) -> s, (s) -> false);
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you! So, a regular "map" returns a Stream<Set<String>> but the "flatMap" returns a Stream<String> for the collector?

Comment: @user1317512 If your regular map returns `anchorlookup.get(s).keySet()`, then it would map each String to a Set<String> and return a Stream<Set<String>>. If you convert the Set<String> to a Stream<String> (by `anchorlookup.get(s).keySet().stream()`), flatMap would flatten all those streams to a single Stream<String>.

Answer (score 5):

[Eran's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24940950/1441122) of `flatMap` is a good one, +1.

This can be simplified somewhat by using `Map.values()` instead of `Map.keySet()`, since the map's keys aren't used for any other purpose than to retrieve the values. Streaming the result of `Map.values()` gives a `Stream<Map<String,Short>>`. Here we don't care about the inner map's values, so we can use `keySet()` to extract the keys, giving a `Stream<Set<String>>`. Now we just `flatMap` these sets into `Stream<String>`. Finally we send the results into the collector as before.

The resulting code looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Map<String, Map<String, Short>> anchorLookup;

    public void checkMissingAnchors() {
        Map<String, Boolean> anchorfound = anchorLookup.values().stream()
            .map(Map::keySet)
            .flatMap(Set::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> false));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is another good suggestion; particularly since I have discovered that the subsequent Map ".get()" method has a slight amount of overhead that it adds to the process. Thank you! Also plus 1 for reinforcing the fact that I was far too verbose with the method calls, and that the double colon operator works very well here.